# Serial upvoting or Bug?

Tags: support, tactical-upvoting

**Yesterday**

[image]

Time stamps:

- 2010-05-11 06:11:22Z
- 2010-05-11 06:12:38Z
- 2010-05-11 06:14:06Z

---

**Today**

[image]

Time stamps:

- 2010-05-12 02:50:59Z
- 2010-05-12 02:51:26Z
- 2010-05-12 02:52:02Z

Answer (score 2):

Very close to 1m30s between each.  Questions only.  Three at a time (though they could go one more without triggering the script..).  It does look suspicious.

I suspect a serial voter rather than a bug.  That said, I can't imagine what they gain by making you look good.  I don't think it's you—unless you posted on meta as a carefully crafted misdirect!

Comment: phony? Nope :) The up votes are recorded in the database, so it can be verified.

Comment: oh, and notice that 2 questions are on both cases. A different account must be used if there is a serial voter.

Comment: @Nick: Never said it was phony.

Comment: "... a carefully crafted misdirect" <---

Comment: @Nick: Ah, that was just some (apparently poor) humor suggesting the votes were fraudulent (but not phony :P). (E.g. if you had you upvoted yourself from a sock puppet account.)

Comment: sock puppet account? oops, you busted me!

Comment: Quick, someone search the user DB for Nick A, Nick B, Nick C and Nick E!

Comment: Sorry, but `1:16`, `1:28`, `0:27` and `0:36` are *not* "very close to 1:30 each".

Comment: @RegDwight: You're right, it's worse than I saw at first glance.  Why did you quote "very close to 1:30 each"?