# Hidden lover and upvotes, fatal attraction?

Tags: support, up-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nicely discouraging serial upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49651/nicely-discouraging-serial-upvoting)

Sometimes I get a burst of upvotes on my questions\answers.

It happened just one hour ago, but it's not the first time.

Is it casual, do I need to be thankful or do I need to be worried (the system bans me because it thinks that I'm cheating)?

Comment: Maybe because sometimes you have a burst of GOOD questions and answers?

Comment: This http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49651/nicely-discouraging-serial-upvoting discusses the phenomenon.

Comment: @Geoffrey Uhm, i doubt it :P

Comment: I sometimes get the same thing in the opposite direction. I would also like to make the exp differences overt: the system gives you boosts in exp because you have 9.5k, for me I get negative boosts because I have less than 3k. I've been publicizing this treatment for a while now, and this question should be closed as a dupe of my previous questions/answers/comments.

Comment: If you found that someone has boiled your pet bunny, then I would be worried....

Comment: @Michael: I take the trouble to cook for you people, and you repay me by being worried?

Comment: @voyager - Well if you use oregano and garlic, i could give it a try.

Comment: @Evan Repeat after me: REPUTATION!!!

Comment: @Earlz I think @Evan simply is a Hendrix aficionado! The first track on "Bold As Love" is in fact named "Exp". (unable to find a good YouTube link I'm afraid, posting "Bold As Love" instead. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdIvyXgM2Rg&feature=related)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say it goes something like this:

User spots one of your answers, and out of curiosity clicks through to your profile, then opens all of your questions and answers, likes them and upvotes them.

Comment: Nope, it's always the 5-10 *most recent* contributions, usually in many different tags.

Comment: Cool, so it's love at first sight :).

Comment: @systempuntoout, as an aside, I suspect that a lot of Jon Skeet and others' rep-harvesting comes from this.

Comment: That started happening to me as well, shortly after I put the flair iframe on my blog. Most of my blog readers come from Google searches on compiler errors, how to implement xyz, etc. I suspect they just click through and occasionally up-vote. I'm not complaining :)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, now, nobody panic, or you're likely to startle it and then we'll never see where this goes.

The truth is, the Trilogy server is emergent AI; it's almost to the point of sentience. It has taken to actually reading the individual questions and answers and voting on the ones it likes or dislikes. It's not yet intelligent enough to vote on the quality of the post -- is it a good question or answer? Is it technically accurate? These are questions it doesn't care about. Right now it's about aesthetics. Is it pretty? Does it fit some pattern distinguisable to only itself? These are how it currently votes.

And if it finds a user it likes or dislikes, it pores through that user's posts and upvotes or downvotes a few before it gives up and moves on to another question/answer from the active tab.

As I said... no sudden moves. We want to see how far this emergent behavior will go. Will it achieve self awareness? we want to find out.

Answer (score 4):

Me too, I was considering a "I'm being stalked!" self-help post here on Meta.

Well... Those secret admirers have to have some reason to do what they do. Let's assume it's because we're so awesome, cherish the thought and whenever we wake up to find a burst of upvotes in our recent tab, let's accept it with gratitude.

As for what the system is going to think, it seems to be way more lenient with bursts of upvotes than it is with bursts of downvotes (wrongly if you ask me, as these cases are clearly frivolous voting patterns with no regard to the quality of the contribution, but well. I'm not complaining too loudly).

Comment: If it is secret admirers, the next question is: why do they upvote in bursts and not evenly?

Comment: Sometimes I'll view a user's profile and check out some of his/her answers and I might throw in a couple of votes here and there.  Off-topic: Hey Pekka, why the name change to Questions?

Comment: @Geoffrey well, passion *is* an unpredictable force! :) @Andy http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/49462/feature-request-vanity-urls/

Comment: @Andy, He wants everyone to browse his profile [*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49463) :-) , btw I do same thing too

Comment: @S.Mark crap, I should have added some Google Ads to my profile, true! :)

Comment: @S.Mark, @Questions: lol that's hilarious.

Comment: @Geoffrey: Like @Andy, I will also sometimes see an answer which intrigues me to visit a person's profile. Either it was exceptional, well thought out and clear, very clever, etc, or sometimes a good answer which was downvoted for unknown reasons. Upon visiting their page I often find more answers of the same quality, and vote to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Same story [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49641/serial-upvoting-or-bug), and it's repeated an hour ago.

I start to believe that's an automated procedure, somehow.

Comment: automated procedure... automated procedure.... Maybe it's *Jeff*?

Comment: @Questions, or perhaps user -1 [gone wild](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091949/) :)

Comment: I like the idea of Jeff mass upvoting users he is infatuated with **because he can!** much better. But it could of course be user -1 finally reaching consciousness (and eventually killing us all.) Either way, we shall find out!