# Judging/Justifying a Sock Puppets Account

Tags: discussion, sock-puppets

I am not happy with the way the sock puppets account are judged in this community. I have been targeted many times.

The place where I work, I try to encourage everyone to use stackoverflow, and post some questions, answer some question and most of them do also, but most of them they get bored too soon and leave the community. And to be frank, I do admit to influence them to vote my questions and answer few times.

So, from the moderator point of view there are multiple account from same IP, highly inactive, and voting same account time and again. I know it looks likes they are self inflected But still, they are not voting sock puppets, you cannot merge there account to mine, or simply remove them.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> And to be frank, I do admit to influence them to vote my questions and answer few times

I think I see where your problems begin...

Comment: OK, I am guilty of doing that. But how can you remove their accounts, and also merge some account to mine. This is wrong.

Comment: The rest of us wish we could make people vote for us too.

Comment: @George, Dont do it, few votes from them, and they are gone or merged with your account.

Comment: If they had *also* voted for other people, they wouldn't have been merged. But when 10+ people have the same pattern of votes (on the order of 20 out of 22 for Starx, with some going 20/20), well...

Comment: @Starx: just to be sure, you're not also asking them to vote *my* answer, are you? Because... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64091

Comment: @Vonc, funny....but I am not responsible for those vote ups. I didn't even knew you, other than today. Besides... you are in much trouble than me....